# Why my reusable component doesn't work with "setInterval"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here is my `<Loader />` component. I'm making it so I can pass the text it is rendering and the speed as props. The code would make much more sense:

```
class Loader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: props.text
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    const stopper = this.props.text + '...';
    this.interval = window.setInterval(function(){
      if (this.state.text === stopper) {
        this.setState(function () {
          return {
            text: this.props.text
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.setState(function (prevState) {
          return {
            text: prevState.text + '.'
          }
        })
      }
    }.bind(this), this.props.speed)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    console.log('cleared interval')
    window.clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
```

when component unmount's I get that message that I'm logging. I get no errors and my component doesn't work as expected. It only shows 'Loading' when I expect an animation with running three dots.

oh and here is the props:

```
Loader.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  speed: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
}

Loader.defaultProps = {
  text: 'Loading',
  speed: 300,
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this with greater speed values, like 1000?

Comment: yap. Still the same

Comment: @karolis2017 Could you show `render` method of `loader` and how you are rendering it from `parent`

Comment: Testing the loader as the top-level component, it certainly seems to work - https://jsfiddle.net/w44gds01/. Which version of React are you using? Note that the fiddle doesn't have propTypes defined

Comment: I was rendering my text as `{this.props.text}` not state lol. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was rendering my text as `{this.props.text}` not state in my render method. All good now.